# Any article is required before [new] if following noun is singular?

Tags: articles

When `s` is omitted from following line,

```
New Kids On The Block
```

Any article(definite/indefinite) is required?

```
A New Kid On The Block
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, an article (either "a" or "the") would be needed. Also, unless referring to a band by that name, the individual words would never be capitalized.

Comment: New wave music.